# What's the point of firstindex in Julia?

Tags: julia

From documentation it says [firstindex()](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.firstindex) finds the first index of a collection. Why not just use 1? What could be the case when it's not 1?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The first index is not necessarily 1 because Julia supports [custom indexing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/offset-arrays/#man-custom-indices-1). To understand why it is useful, you can't beat [Tim Holy's blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/04/offset-arrays/).

**Custom indices allow you to encode information about your data in the indexing pattern itself**: sometimes it is more natural to start counting from one, sometimes from zero, sometimes from some more arbitrary number.

Other times, such as when you are writing generic algorithms, you do not really care about the specific index. In which case you can use abstractions such as [`firstindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.firstindex), [`lastindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.lastindex), and [`eachindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachindex).

Most often, it is better to avoid referring to an index altogether and just iterate over a collection's elements (e.g. `for x in xs`).

Julia allows you to use the most effective strategy for your data.

Comment: "In which case you can use abstractions such as `firstindex`, `lastindex`, and `eachindex`. You could say that Julia [sets the standards for you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3KSpeiRPTc)...

Comment: Can you add links to documentation for firstindex(), lastindex(), and eachindex()?

Answer (score 16):

There are special array types like for example [OffsetArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/OffsetArrays.jl) which can have arbitrary indices.